# xml to json conversion - How to transform child node and child elements from xml to json

Tags: json, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

we are trying to do xml to json conversion.
child elements 'EmployeeCode' is not recognizing. Error:Error executing XSLT at line 15 : xml-to-json: Child elements of  must have a key attribute. Need to consider the child elements and subelements in xml to json conversion.

xmlFile:

```
<root>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <Age>42</Age>
    <item>
        <number>314</number>
        <name>foo</name>
        <EmployeeCode>
            <id>F21</id>
            <Department>
                <Designation>Engineer</Designation>
            </Department>
            <Status>Contractor</Status>
        </EmployeeCode>
    </item>
    <item>
        <number>42</number>
        <name>bar</name>
        <EmployeeCode>
            <id>F24</id>
            <Department>
                <Designation>Manager</Designation>
            </Department>
            <Status>Full-time</Status>
        </EmployeeCode>
    </item>
    <data>test</data>
</root>
```

xslcode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
      <map>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                      <array key="{local-name()}">
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                      </array>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </map>
  </xsl:template>
  
      <xsl:template match="node()|@*">        
        <!-- Including any attributes it has and any child nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Json file:

```
{
    "Name": "Alex",
    "Age": 42,
    "item": [
      {
        "number": 314,
        "name": "foo",
        "EmployeeCode": {
          "id": "F21",
          "Department": {
            "Designation": "Engineer"
          },
          "Status": "Contractor"
        }
      },
      {
        "number": 42,
        "name": "bar",
        "EmployeeCode": {
          "id": "F24",
          "Department": {
            "Designation": "Manager"
          },
          "Status": "Full-time"
        }
      }
    ],
    "data": "test"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt to improve the previous code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```