# XSLT to convert a XML to JSON which may have multiple repeated nodes

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, xml-to-json

I want to convert a XML to JSON using XSLT. But I am facing few issues.

**Input XML**

```
<notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
  <OrganizationId>123</OrganizationId>
  <ActionId>123</ActionId>
  <SessionId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  <EnterpriseUrl>qwe</EnterpriseUrl>
  <PartnerUrl>qwe</PartnerUrl>
  <Notification>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <sObject xsi:type="sf:Opportunity" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
      <sf:Id>ao123</sf:Id>
      <sf:Amount>60000.0</sf:Amount>
      <sf:CreatedDate>2014-11-26T14:45:52.000Z</sf:CreatedDate>
      <sf:IsClosed>false</sf:IsClosed>
    </sObject>
  </Notification>
</notifications>
```

**Expected Output JSON**

```
{
  "notifications": {
    "OrganizationId": "123",
    "ActionId": "123",
    "SessionId": {
      "@nil": "true"
    },
    "EnterpriseUrl": "qwe",
    "PartnerUrl": "qwe",
    "Notification": [
      {
        "Id": "ao123",
        "sObject": {
          "@type": "sf:Opportunity",
          "Id": "ao123",
          "Amount": "60000.0",
          "CreatedDate": "2014-11-26T14:45:52.000Z",
          "IsClosed": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566620/15132538) I got XSLT and I have tried it. This is the XSLT code I have tried. [Fiddle link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFksq1w/1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  

  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So below are few issues which I am facing

- `notifications` node is missing in json output, it is the root node in the xml.
- `Notification` should be a json array even if I receive one
   item in XML

Please note that I don't want to hard code node names other than `notifications` and `Notification` in XSLT code as I may receive different nodes under node `Notification`.

I am looking for XSLT which can handle my requirements

Comment: Your xml Notification node is not valid for array, you have to learn xml rules at first

Comment: @Serge What i am saying there is chance of getting multiple Notification node in xml, In this sample xml input there are two Notification and i am getting json as array which is expected https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFksq1w/2 .So when i have one Notification node also i should get json array.That means Notification node should be array. Json output format should be uniform irrespective of number of Notification xml node

Comment: My point is you have to  learn how to create XML array , before trying to deserialize it to array.  Now your syntax shows that it is an object. How do you think a compiler should know that you want it to be an array instead?

Comment: I am able to handle array issue with using proper conditions in cases of for-each-group. Here is the xslt https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFksq1w/4 . But still root node notifications is missing in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the requirements (outer map/JSON object, always making `Notification` an array) can of course be inserted into the XSLT code by modifying what you linked to (please make sure next time you show the XSLT in the question as well):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
        <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </map>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or current-grouping-key() = QName('http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound', 'Notification')">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code you grabbed from another question/answer I think was not written with XML having elements with attributes in mind; I have tried to adapt it below with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
        <map>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </map>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <string key="@{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[* or @*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or current-grouping-key() = QName('http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound', 'Notification')">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                      </xsl:apply-templates>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That seems to give the wanted attributes as `@name` properties of a JSON object/map for your sample; I can't guarantee it will work in general.

Comment: Nice. This works as expected. As you suggested I have added the XSLT in the question as well now. Only small issue now is in the expected JSON also have the attrib from xml   "@nil": "true" under SessionId and also "@type": "sf:Opportunity" under SObject. These are not present in XSLT output now. How i can manage these attributes

Comment: @techresearch, I have added a second, adapted XSLT sample that tries to process attributes as well. Seems to do the job for your sample, it is always difficult to tell if you adapt some previous code meant for simpler input to more complex requirements if it doesn't break something or if it works in general, so test carefully on your own.

Comment: Thanks!! , This works as expected. As you mentioned, I will make sure to test it thoroughly.